# Video lectures on Real Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, online-resources

One of the most annoying gaps in my math education is Real analysis.

I tried hard, but all I could find are either Harvey Mudd College lectures or [MathDoctorBob](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7B37EFE678A682CE). The latter are too short and the former are in horrendous format, I can barely make out what is written on the blackboard.

Ideally I'd like the lectures to cover topics such as proofs of continuity, differentiation, some main inequalities, $\limsup$ and $\liminf$, uniform/pointwise convergence and continuity, dominated and monotone convergence and maybe a bit more.

So if anyone knows if this material is available online, I'd be quite grateful.

Comment: If you speak portuguese, try these: http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=programa-de-verao-2011-analise-na-reta
They are from Elon Lages Lima, a well known brazilian Mathematician. Those lectures are from the world-wide known IMPA, from 2011.
I don't know if there are subtitles...

Comment: No, sorry, I don't speak Portuguese. I'd prefer English.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but it is possible that they have subtitles.

Comment: I have a (very smart) friend who is fond of the [ICTP TV](http://www.ictp.tv) lectures. A quick glance at the offerings shows that they have a collection of undergraduate lectures in analysis (real and complex). Downside: the video and sound quality may not be to your liking.

Comment: Roughly the lower level half of what you're asking for is covered in [these lecture notes](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf) of mine on honors calculus. (To me, *honors calculus* is a flavor of undergraduate real analysis, and not the least ambitious possible flavor.)

Comment: At the risk of making worse the fact that I left what may not be an appropriate answer to your question: may I ask why you are specifically interested in video lectures rather than written lecture notes?  To my mind, the big advantage of a lecture is that you can ask questions of the lecturer.  This is not possible when watching a pre-taped video lecture.  It can be easier and quicker to learn the tiniest bit of subject X from a video lecture than from written notes, but it sounds like you want to learn things thoroughly.  For this I really think the written word is superior.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I suppose that there are things which are easier done when speaking than when typing lecture notes - like handwaving, drawing pictures, getting big picture across... (I am not saying that they are impossible in written notes; but they seem to be communicated in spoken word more easily.) So maybe this might be an advantage of videos. Another possibility - when someone is teaching, they are limited by the time. In written notes, there is no limit, so it is possible to digress, go in detail. That might be another reason why some people would prefer a video from actual lecture.

Comment: @Marra They do not have subtitles.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try: http://www.uccs.edu/math/student-resources/video-course-archive.html

They have a Real Analysis course listed, Math 533 Real Analysis I - Fall 2007. They are good, though not that challenging.

You may need to create a [free] account to view the videos.

If you really don't want to make an account the videos start with:

http://cmes.uccs.edu/Fall2007/Math533/pages/video3.html

and go up to /video24.html. There is, for some reason, no video 1 or 2.

Comment: Very good video lectures!

Comment: 404 not found on the first link

Comment: Please update the link with something valid

Comment: Seems new link is:
http://cmes.uccs.edu/Fall2007/Math533/archive.php but it's not working for me at the moment so I don't want to edit the post until it does.

Comment: It looks like the updated link for UCCS's cource archive is https://www.uccs.edu/math/vidarchive, and the link to Intro to Analysis in particular is https://uccs1.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Sessions/List.aspx#folderID=%22cc363157-a258-4a68-b3a3-a98c01633180%22.

Answer (score 8):

[Video Lectures in Mathematics](http://pinterest.com/mathematicsprof/) , This site contains links to math videos, withch includes a lot of mathematical topics for example Topology, Algebra, Complex and real analysis and anything that you think.

Specifically, the site has 38 videos in real analysis: [Analysis, Real](http://pinterest.com/mathematicsprof/analysis-real/).

Answer (score 6):

Check out these YouTube [video lectures](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3A87B93CB9912EC1) by S K Ray on real analysis.

Answer (score 4):

This was basically already posted by Alex - but Joel Feistein has his 2nd year undergrad introductory course to real analysis (complete with camcasts/videos, notes, exercises and solutions) posted here http://unow.nottingham.ac.uk/resources/resource.aspx?hid=c6c045f6-286d-6b9f-b96c-36a998632fc3 and his 4th year undergrad course on functional analysis here http://unow.nottingham.ac.uk/resources/resource.aspx?hid=c9eec1dc-8c27-9949-dc16-2728edf6c994.

They are both quite good (the first one introduced me, at the time an engineering undergrad, to rigorous mathematics and how to do proofs and I cannot be happier of having watched it).

Comment: True, although I found them kind hard)

Comment: Did you try doing the exercises as you went along? Doing them made all the difference for me.

Comment: Yes I'm. The part on uniform vs pointwise convergence in quite helpful

Comment: pages not found

Answer (score 2):

In fact I ended up using Nottingham Uni's lectures on Youtube, like this one:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mB4Yny0T3HA

Answer (score 1):

This one based on Rudin's book looks good too:

*https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcR4No3nvxFDg6VfaO8paSOv4ClAlyzon*

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same and came across these video lectures by Dr. Jaikrishan J, [Real Analysis](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7oBzLzHZ1wX7NQM0Y7QAVt_443nmq2hk).

As far as I know, these videos constitute one of the best lectures on the topic of Real Analysis. There are a total of 125 videos in this playlist of length varying from 2 mins to 30 mins, summing up to 1 day, 10 hours, 16 minutes, 24 seconds (~2056 minutes).

Example:

Consider this video: [7.1 Motivation for infinite series](https://youtu.be/un7kptcZyt8)

In this video he considers the case of a chocolate bar with promotional offer on its wrappers. And goes on to show that the chocolate with the wrapper is worth more than the chocolate. By this he shows how infinite series emerges in real life situations. All of this is presented in a very logical manner.

The language of instruction is English.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Francis Su 's YouTube Lectures on Real Analysis

this web page contain the links:
http://analysisyawp.blogspot.com/

Comment: very low resolution - op stated these in their original post

Answer (score 0):

3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLil-R4o6jmGhUqtKbZf0LIFKd-xN__g_M real analysis 1 of NTU ( more advanced version of 1)

4 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLil-R4o6jmGhkuZPmKL_A5Y7N4HOsa1nX
real analysis 2 (continuation of 3)

these lectures are in Chinese, but he writes in english and his handwritting should be clear enough for you to read. I really enjoyed it and plan to go through all of them.

There isnt a lot of good RA lectures on YT, so hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a friendly list of lecture recordings of real analysis. From lecture 4 quality of lectures is good but first three are also understandable.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4fpys7KOcYhcH3jWB2dBGUSMpXGMOVDc

Answer (score -1):

1 http://ocw.aca.ntu.edu.tw/ntu-ocw/index.php/ocw/cou/104S115 real analysis 1 at National Taiwan University ( Called Calculus for math majors 1)

2 http://ocw.aca.ntu.edu.tw/ntu-ocw/index.php/ocw/cou/104S210 real analysis 2 at National Taiwan University ( Called Calculus for math majors 2)