# "Modern analysis" books in languages other than English or Russian

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I confess that I am not quite sure about the usefulness of this question, but after getting to know of a few textbooks in German and Portuguese, I've certainly gotten curious:

Do you know of textbooks on analysis (anything from real analysis of several variables, through complex analysis, up to measure theory and functional analysis) in any language other than English or Russian? I suggest this exclusion because English books are definitely the most numerous and well known over here, while Russian books are already famous, as demonstrated by the amounts of requests for specifically Russian/Soviet textbooks in math.se.

I figure that at the very least this might inspire some people to peek books written in languages that they are learning. Who knows, perhaps there are some hidden gems.

Comment: Video lectures OK? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312492/video-lectures-on-real-analysis

Comment: I figure that, if this question is considered legitimate, it should be a community wiki. And perhaps "modern analysis" might be misleading: I intended to use it in an overarching sense, as--I think--Dieudonné intended to use the term.

Comment: Henri Cartan's three amazing books (*Differential Calculus*, *Differential Forms*, *Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions of One or Several Complex Variables*) were originally written in French. Also, I believe Amann and Escher's three volumes Analysis I, II, III were all originally written in German and then translated.

Comment: For books in Portuguese, see https://impa.br/publicacoes/projeto-euclides/

Comment: The variety of excellent analysis books in French and German is not far from that in English and Russian, and that is not to mention Italian, Chinese, Japanese, and so on. That being said, solely at the introductory level comparable to Apostol and Rudin (though perhaps extending to Lebsgue integration theory), in German you have the books by Forster, Königsberger, Amann/Escher, Walter, Heuser, Fichtenholz, Erwe, Grauert/Lieb, Ostrowski. See the bibliography at the end of this document: https://ganymed.math.uni-heidelberg.de/~lehre/notes/ana1/analysis1.pdf

Comment: Strange that you mention "Russian" and not "French", a language in which many "modern analysis" texts have been written, in particular the amazing series of 9  books by Dieudonné "Eléments d'analyse". The first one, "Fondements de l'Analyse Moderne" is a masterpiece and very accessible (It is had been originally written in English).

Comment: @NicolasM.Gutierrez I am interested in the "modern analysis" books written in English or Russian. Can you please share your experience?

Answer (score 4):

This gives me a very nice excuse to talk about two of my favourite German math books of all time:

---

For one there is the three-volume book set **Analysis (I-III)** by *Herbert Amann* and *Joachim Escher*. These books were originally written in German, but were translated into English later on. These books are definitely one of the "definitive" undergrad analysis books in Germany. They encompass nearly everything that is taught in undergrad analysis classes, except functional analysis. 
What makes them so great is their strict almost Bourbaki-style build-up of analysis: starting from basic logic predicates they establish everything one needs to know to get to topics like Stokes theorem or the Lebesgue integral. They cover:

**Analysis I**: This book starts from basic logic and "naivé" set theory and establishes the basic notions of rings, fields and vector spaces. Then the natural numbers and the real numbers are constructed which is followed by everything you'd espect in a first-semester analysis course: sequences, series, continuous functions on metric spaces and derivatives on the reals. The book concludes with sequences of functions.

**Analysis II**: The results about sequences of functions are swiftly put to use to construct the Riemann-Cauchy integral on Banach spaces. This is followed by an expansive treatise of differential calculus on Banach spaces including the implicit function theorem and the inverse function theorem. This theory is then applied to ordinary differential equations and variational calculus proving the Picard-Lindelöf-theorem and the Euler-Lagrange equations. The second part of the book is devoted to submanifolds of $\mathbb{R^d}$ and curve-integrals. This is applied to establish basic results in complex analysis.

**Analysis III**: Basic measure theory is introduced culminating in the Carathéodory extension theorem and the construction of the Lebesgue- and Hausdorff-measures. Then the (nunmerical) Lebesgue integral and the Bochner integral on Banach spaces is constructed with their standard convergence theorems and the transformation theorem. This is applied to $L^p$-spaces and the Fourier transformation. The second part of the book treats general submanifolds and the theory of differential forms on them. Integration of differential on submanifolds of $\mathbb{R^d}$ is defined using the Lebesgue integral. Then as the finalé of the series Stokes theorem is proved and the theory is applied to vector analysis.

---

Then there is the book **Maß- und Integrationstheorie** ("Measure- and Integration theory") by *Jürgen Elstrodt*. It seems that there is no english translation. What is very special about this book that it has many historical remarks and biographies of the mathematicians which contributed to the field.

The name of the book suggest what the book is about: It very thoroughly covers the theory of rings, pre-measures, measures, $\sigma$-algebras and all that. Various extension and uniqueness theorems are proved. This all is used to construct the abstract Lebesgue integral. Then the various notions of convergence one has in measure theory are introduced and at the end the theory of signed measures and measures on topological spaces including the Haar measure and the Riesz representation theorem is covered.

---

A honourable mention is **Grundkurs Funktionalanalysis** ("Basics of Functional Analysis") by *Winfried Kaballo*, again not translated into english. It is a very structured textooks with great explanations. It contains everything an undergrad course in functional analysis would be about: Banach- and Hilbert space theory, the "pillar"-theoreoms of functional analysis like Hahn-Banach and concludes with the spectal theory of self-adjpoint operators. The spectral theorem is proved for compact operators and a first glimpse on unbounded operators is given. It also has a continuation which is called **Aufbaukurs Funktionalanalysis** ("Advanced Functional Analysis"), but I've never read that.

Comment: Great list! 
Do you happen to be familiar with Klaus Jänich's books? I am just curious, because I've seen books on somewhat diverse topics written by him and I wonder if he is kind of "big" in Germany or something.

Comment: @NicolasM.Gutierrez Yes, his books are  great! And they are very much valued her in Gemrany. Maybe I'll add them to my list later, e.g. his book "Vektoranalysis" is a masterpiece.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of French ones.  In functional analysis, Riesz & Nagy "[Leçons d'Analyse Fonctionelle](https://books.google.ca/books?id=455fzQEACAAJ)" comes to mind.

Comment: Do you think you could add others, for reference?

Comment: @NicolasM.Gutierrez *Éléments d'Analyse* (9 vols.) by Dieudonné, *Analyse* (4 vols.) by Schwartz, *Analyse mathématique* (4 vols.) by Godement for comprehensive multi-volume works. There are too many single-volume works to name, but apart from the books by Cartan already mentioned, the functional analysis book by Brézis and the complex analysis book by Dolbeault stand out.